# I ALWAYS think that. What's the meaning of ALWAYS in that structure?

Tags: grammar, meaning, adverbs

I wonder what's the meaning that "ALWAYS" is trying to convey when used in simple present sentences such as:

> **I always think that** John should stop drinking.
>   **I always think that** Victoria lies too much to be trusted.
>   **I always think that** Peter has an ulterior motive when he kisses up to Jenny.

Recently, I heard someone say that "*I always think that*" is not logical. Because it expresses that someone is thinking about something all along.
I think that's not the meaning. But I would like if someone could clarify what the mean really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I **always think** that Victoria lies too much to be trusted.

means every time you think about (consider) her trustworthiness, you believe that you can't trust her. Of course you think of many other things around the same time too.

If you said:

> I **think** that Victoria lies too much to be trusted.

it could be that you thought that on just one occasion. Or you are making a general statement that you expect/hope might change over time.